# nginx streaming server serving stream that causes VLC to reload in a loop

Tags: nginx, streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I explained the problem in this [Video Stack Exchange Question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/network-stream-reloading-in-a-loop-nginx-rtmp-streaming-server) as I don't believe this is something code related (e.g. a bug).

It may be a useful information for dev's however, that I did **not** compile nginx from source. I mention that explicitly, because searching the web, it seems like building from source is the recommended way for nginx/rtmp setups. I could not find a bug report, however, that would explain this behavior.

I feel like I am overseeing something stupid.

For the sake of completeness, I will post the configuration files. Also, dont miss out the live-demo and have fun playing around with the streaming server linked in the other Post ;)

Happy Coding!

nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

rtmp {
    include /etc/nginx/streams-enabled/*;
}
```

rtmp server (in streams-enabled/)

```
server {

        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
                live                    on;
                hls                     on;
                hls_path                /home/streamer/hls;
                hls_nested              on;
                hls_fragment            3s;
                hls_playlist_length     30s;
                hls_base_url            http://0.0.0.0:3456/hls;
                on_publish              http://0.0.0.0:3456/auth;
                # Recent versions of IE need this for normal playback.
                wait_video              on; # start audio with video
                # force hls
                deny play all;

        }
}
```

http-server (in sites-enabled/)

```
server {

    listen      3456;

    location /hls {

        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }

        types {
        application/dash+xml mpd;
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root       /home/streamer/;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the stream configuration.

vlc -vv http://104.248.36.47:3644/hls/debug/index.m3u8 ouput revealed:

> [00007f0594002580] main stream debug: connecting to 0.0.0.0 port 3644 ...
>
> [00007f0594002580] main stream error: connection error: Connection refused

...

> [00007f0594002580] adaptive stream debug: Retrieving http://0.0.0.0:3644/hlsdebug/75.ts @0

Note that it says hlsdebug instead of the expected hls/debug

After adding a '/' to the hls_base_url, and  changing 0.0.0.0 to the public IP, it works.

I do not understand fully tho why 0.0.0.0 would not work..